# How to use the dcerpc library implement by samba?

Tags: rpc, samba, dce

Now I have a task to write rpc server and client by the dcerpc library implement by samba. I wanted to get some info from samba.org and the source in past 4 days. Unfortunately i get nothing useful to me.

Is there an example or tutorial for writing a rpc server and client （RPC Helloworld）by the samba's rpc implement???

Thx a lot